# Error compiling simple C++ program

Tags: c++

im trying to compile my first program in c++, it's a pretty simple code and i dont get why it dont compile and give me lots of errors:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
std::cout << "Game Over";
return 0;
}
```

and these are the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
  std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&      std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >       (std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in untitled-7bd2fc.o
...
```

and so on.

Comment: These are linker error messages, how is the linker called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile (and link) it with `g++` instead of `gcc`.